# Is it possible to rotate a face in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a cube from which I extruded its top face.
[image]
[image]
Now I want to rotate that top face. Is there a way to rotate a face in geometry nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minimally:

[image]

.. with the top of the extrusion selected..

[image]

Comment: aaaaaaah...we have an extrude mesh node!!!!!! How amazing is that!!!!!

Comment: Thanks a million!